# Searching for MongoDB ISODate Using Spring Data @Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, match, spring-data-mongodb, aggregation, isodate

I have a Spring API connecting to a MongoDB database. I am trying to use Spring's `@Aggregation` to find entries in a "Shipment" document which have a "shipDate" later than the date specified by the user.

Here is an example of my repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ShipmentRepository extends MongoRepository<Shipment, String> {
    @Aggregation("{ '$match': { shipDate: {$gt: ISODate(?0)} } }")
    int findShippedAfterDate(String date);
}
```

The value being passed as `date` is *"2020-06-16"*. I am using @Aggregation instead of @Query because there will be a $group opperation following the $match once I get this portion working.

It seems that using `?0` inside `ISODate()` does not work properly and results in the following error:

> JSON reader expected a string but found '?0'

I have tried the following syntax variations:

- `shipDate: {$gt: ISODate('?0')}`
- `shipDate: {$gt: ISODate('$?0')}`

Both result in the following error, which I believe is caused by `?0` not actually being replaced by the value:

> org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid date format.

I am confident the issue is with `?0` not being replaced by the string value because the query works as expected when the string is used instead of the variable place holder:

```
@Aggregation("{ '$match': { shipDate: {$gt: ISODate('2020-06-16')} } }")
```

Is there a simple syntax mistake I am making? Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: i have the same problem as you, were you able to find a solution?  thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using `$dateToString` to convert the ISODate stored in MongoDB to a string that can be matched against the date provided by the user and then adding it to each entry using `$addFields`. However, I believe this method may have the following issue:

- Inefficient because it will add a `dateString` field to every returned entry.

I'm am not certain that this will be an issue because it depends on how MongoDB handles `$addFields` when followed by `$match`. If it only adds the field to entries that are returned by the `$match`, it will be much more efficient.

Working `@Aggregation` example:

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
        "{ '$addFields': { 'dateString': { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$shipDate'} } }  }",
        "{ '$match': { dateString: {$gte: ?0} } }" })
```